# DevEnv hanging GetPricvateContextsPerfCounters

Tags: perfmon, devenv

Visual Studio 2013 keeps locking up several times a day. I am running a fairly large MVC 4 project and suddenly the processor maxes out. I have installed perfmon and GetPricvateContextsPerfCounters has over 80% of the CPU.

None of my colleagues working on the same code base are getting these hangs.

It will eventually settle down if left for a few hours or I am forced to restart the IDE.

I have disabled all add-ons, I only have Resharper running. I can't really afford to develop without resharper. So disabling that is no solution.

This is seriously costing me a lot of project time. Anybody else had this problem? any possible solutions?

Any help very greatly appreciated.

Mal

Comment: Does disabling ReSharper solve the hang though?  That would point to whether you need to contact them about a possible defect.